# Zip arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = [a, b, c]
```

What I want to get as a result is:

```
[[1, a], [2, b], [3, c]]
```

It seems simple but I just can't figure out.

I want the result to be one array with each of the elements from the two arrays zipped together.

Comment: Note that array map() is not supported in IE8, if that is a problem. Polyfill here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate as it only asks for *2* arrays to be zipped instead of *N* arrays. Thus it is a special case for which there are specialized, more performant solutions.

Answer (score 365, accepted):

Use the `map` method:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

var c = a.map(function(e, i) {
  return [e, b[i]];
});

console.log(c)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/2ah8u/)

Comment: Total javascript noob here, but I was under the impression that the index has to come before the element? that is, .map(function(index,element))?

Comment: @runawaykid The answer is correct. You can see the [MDN map documentation on the callback parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters). Params are (in order): `currentvalue`, `index`, `array`

Comment: Using the arrow notation is even a bit nicer: var c = a.map((e, i) => [e, b[i]]);

Comment: How would you create a dictionary/object from this?

Comment: @Climax Use forEach instead, e.g., `const obj = Object.create(null); a.forEach((e, i) => obj[e] = b[i]);`

Comment: There is also the [`<array>.entries` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) which was added to JS in ES2015, with which the expression in your answer can be written as follows: `Array.from(a.entries()).map(([i, e]) => [e, b[i]]);`. This is more verbose, but may be clearer to those who don't realize that `map` takes a second parameter :-)

Comment: @Climax you can also use reduce for this. `const c = a.reduce((accum, cur, i) => ({ ...accum, [cur]: b[i] }), {});`

Comment: return '\n' + array1[i] + ' - ' + array2[i]; 
------------
write in this way to line break after every iteration.
Check on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Ahsan_Aftab/bc7hd258/

Comment: I implemented a multi-array zip, but too bad I cannot post it here. I may add it to this answer at a later time.

Comment: @runawaykid You (and the others that upvoted your comment) are probably thinking of jQuery's [map](https://api.jquery.com/map/) function, which has that signature (and pre-dates the native JavaScript map function).

Comment: Just note that if the arrays are different lengths, then this will either pad the right side with undefined values (if `a` is longer) or will omit some entries (if `b` is longer).

Comment: the next answer  by @RokoCBuljan is less confusing imo

Comment: If you have two different lengths array and you want to include all elements always I would recommend to use something like this:

https://github.com/gkucmierz/algorithms/blob/master/js/zip.js
```js
const zip = (arr1, arr2) => {
 const zipped = [];
  const len = Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    zipped[i] = [arr1[i], arr2[i]];
  }
  return zipped;
};

console.log(zip(
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [...'abc'],
));
```

Answer (score 139):

### Zip Arrays of **same length**:

Using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const zip = (a, b) => a.map((k, i) => [k, b[i]]);

console.log(zip([1,2,3], ["a","b","c"]));
// [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]]
```

#### Zip Arrays of different length:

Using [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
const zip = (a, b) => Array.from(Array(Math.max(b.length, a.length)), (_, i) => [a[i], b[i]]);

console.log( zip([1,2,3], ["a","b","c","d"]) );
// [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [undefined, "d"]]
```

Using [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const zip = (a, b) => Array(Math.max(b.length, a.length)).fill().map((_,i) => [a[i], b[i]]);

console.log(zip([1,2,3], ["a","b","c","d"]));
// [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [undefined, "d"]]
```

#### Zip Multiple *(n)* Arrays:

```js
const zip = (...arr) => Array(Math.max(...arr.map(a => a.length))).fill().map((_,i) => arr.map(a => a[i]));  
console.log(zip([1,2], [3,4], [5,6])); // [[1,3,5], [2,4,6]]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Foruntanely map worked in my environment nevertheless I've recorded this method just in case.

Comment: This `const zip = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.map((k, i) => [k, arr2[i]]);` is concise and elegant

Comment: Elegant, but faulty. Classic zip must be commutative, this implementation is not. check out with arrays of different length.

Comment: **Thank you** @goteguru, I added two more example for array of different length.

Comment: Thx @RokoC.Buljan, nice.  However I think it should be Math.min. zip comes from the functional languages (just like filter, map, reduce and friends) and it's main purpose is to feeding two streams into one binary computation. The result is undefined anyway if one of them is missing, therefore we should stop early.  Moreover, in FP the streams may be infinite (!) which would mean the above algorithm never stops. Of course it's not the case using js Arrays, but still this is the classic "zip".  (Performance wise: imagine one array has 100k items, and the other has only twelve).

Comment: even shorter :P `const zip = (a, b) => [...Array(Math.max(b.length, a.length))].map((_, i) => [a[i], b[i]]);`

Comment: **For TS:** `const zip = <A1, A2>(a: A1[], b: A2[]) => a.map((k, i) => [k, b[i]] as [A1, A2]);`

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question, and not the one that OP accepted.

Answer (score 9):

#### Zipping by leveraging generator functions

You can also use a [generator function](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_sync-generators.html) to `zip()`.

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3]
const b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

/**
 * Zips any number of arrays. It will always zip() the largest array returning undefined for shorter arrays.
 * @param  {...Array<any>} arrays 
 */
function* zip(...arrays){
  const maxLength = arrays.reduce((max, curIterable) => curIterable.length > max ? curIterable.length: max, 0);
  for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    yield arrays.map(array => array[i]);
  }
}

// put zipped result in an array
const result = [...zip(a, b)]

// or lazy generate the values
for (const [valA, valB] of zip(a, b)) {
  console.log(`${valA}: ${valB}`);  
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The above works for any number of arrays and will `zip()` the longest array so `undefined` is returned as a value for shorter arrays.

#### Zipping of all `Iterables`

Here a function which can be used for all [`Iterables`](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_sync-iteration.html#iterable-iterator-iteratorresult) (e.g. [`Maps`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [`Sets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) or your custom `Iterable`), not just arrays.

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = ["a", "b", "c"];

/**
 * Zips any number of iterables. It will always zip() the largest Iterable returning undefined for shorter arrays.
 * @param  {...Iterable<any>} iterables
 */
function* zip(...iterables) {
  // get the iterator of for each iterables
  const iters = [...iterables].map((iterable) => iterable[Symbol.iterator]());
  let next = iters.map((iter) => iter.next().value);
  // as long as any of the iterables returns something, yield a value (zip longest)
  while(anyOf(next)) {
    yield next;
    next = iters.map((iter) => iter.next().value);
  }

  function anyOf(arr){
    return arr.some(v => v !== undefined);
  }
}

// put zipped result in aa array
const result = [...zip(a, new Set(b))];

// or lazy generate the values
for (const [valA, valB] of zip(a, new Set(b))) {
  console.log(`${valA}: ${valB}`);
}
```

> Obviously it would also be possible to just use `[...Iterable]` to transform any `Iterable` to an array and then use the first function.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3]
const b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

var c = a.reduce((acc, curr, ind) => {
  acc.push([curr, b[ind]]);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(c)
```

With [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3]
const b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const c = [];
a.forEach((el, ind) => {
    c.push([el, b[ind]])
});
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing a solution with imperative programming by a simple `for loop`.

This performs better when doing the **zip** operation on **huge** **data** sets compared to the convenient array functions like `map()` and `forEach()`.

Example:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  result.push([a[i], b[i]]);
}
console.log(result);
```

And if you want a 1 line **simpler** solution then you can use a library like **ramda** which has a [zip](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zip) function.

Example:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const result = R.zip(a, b);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Zip function for 2D arrays**

Here is a function that zips multiple arrays. However, It only works with 2D arrays only.

```js
function zip(listOfLists) {
  return listOfLists[0].map((value, index) => {
      let result = [];

      for(let i=0; i <= listOfLists.length-1 ; i++){
          result[i] = listOfLists[i][index]
      }
      return result;
  });
}
```

This is how you run it.

```
console.log(
  zip(
    [[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]]
  )
);
```