# Calculating the 1d difference of an array

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

```
var a = [1, 5, 7, 3];

console.log(DiffTheArray(a));
```

With the expected result of `[4, 2, -4]`, which is the difference between every two elements of the original array, how would `DiffTheArray` most concisely be implemented?

I was hoping to implement it using slices (`a.slice(1) - a.slice(0,-1)`), but there doesn't seem to be a built-in way of subtracting one array from another in JS.

Comment: How is `-4` derived?

Comment: @guest271314 `3 - 7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also just use the regular reduce function:

```js
function diffTheArray(arr) {
  let diff = [];
  arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    diff.push(b - a);
    return b;
  });
  return diff;
}

var a = [1, 5, 7, 3];
console.log(diffTheArray(a));
```

If you use the `comma operator`, you can get the return onto the same line and take advantage of the lighter syntax of es6:

```js
function diffTheArray(arr) {
  let diff = [];
  arr.reduce((a, b) => (diff.push(b - a), b));
  return diff;
}

console.log(diffTheArray([1, 5, 7, 3]));
```

Comment: I'll check tonight to see if the => operator is supported in [hackmud](http://store.steampowered.com/app/469920/). Your solution is much the same as @guest271314, though I appreciate learning about some tasty syntactic sugar :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduceRight()`

```js
var a = [1, 5, 7, 3];
var res = [];
a.reduceRight(function(a, b, index) {
  res[index] = a - b;
  return b
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Wait, so you're abusing `reduceRight()` to iterate through the array by storing each successive element in the accumulator? COOL!

Comment: Requirement could also probably be achieved with an array set as accumulator where additional logic is included to handle first index of resulting array not being set as `NaN`

Comment: related link using `map` to iterate through two arrays at the same time: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22015771/2832561

Comment: There are several different approaches which could be used to achieve expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate the entire array:

```js
function DiffTheArray(arr) {
  var diffArr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    diffArr.push(arr[i + 1] - arr[i]);
  }

  return diffArr;
}

console.log(DiffTheArray([1, 5, 7, 3]));
```

Comment: I appreciate the explicit method, and I'm sure it's probably pretty fast, but in this case my character count is limited (see [hackmud](http://store.steampowered.com/app/469920/)), so I'm looking for a more concise functional way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how [numpy solves this problem](http://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L38-L94) (`arr[1:] - arr[:-1]`) and [this example of using map with two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22015771/2832561), I was considering the following:

```js
function diffTheArray(arr) {
    return arr.slice(1).map(function(e, i){return e-arr.slice(0,-1)[i];});
}

var a = [1,5,7,3];
console.log(diffTheArray(a));
```

However, this is 90 characters, and I think some of the other answers here are shorter, which is the most important metric for my situation.