# How can I merge two object arrays by index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What would be the best way to combine the two arrays below to get the desired result. I would want them to be combined by index.

Input is:

```
var array1 = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]
var array2 = [[a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h]]
```

Desired output would be:

```
var array3 =[{
              array1:[1,2,3,4],
              array2:[a,b,c,d]
             },
             {
              array1:[4,5,6,7],
              array2:[a,b,c,d]
             }]
```

Any variation of the output would work as long as they are grouped by indexes. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: not a duplicate of what was suggestion. Suggestion out [a,1,b,2] and does not group the way the desired output shows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I zip two arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/how-do-i-zip-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: It not a duplicate because that solution gives you [a,1,b,2] thats not what i am looking for

Comment: See my solution. It's pretty much a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to [How do I zip two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22015684/5743988), except you just change the output format from an array to an object:

```js
var array1 = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]];
var array2 = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h']];

var array3 = array1.map(function(_, i) {
  return {
    array1: array1[i],
    array2: array2[i]
  };
});

console.log(array3);
```

Comment: Oh that is actually the same, for some reason when I clicked on the jsfiddle demo for the answer of that question. And modified the inputs and outputs it didn't come out properly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [matrix transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose), where the 2d array passed is `[array1, array2]`.

**Edit**: It looks like this operation can also be called "zipping" when only two arrays are used. Matrix transposition can support any number of rows, not just two.

```js
var array1 = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [4, 5, 6, 7]
]
var array2 = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
]

function transpose(matrix) {
  return matrix.map(function(_, i) {
    return matrix.map(function(e) {
      return e[i]
    })
  })
}

var result = transpose([array1, array2])

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

If you really want to have nested objects with properties `array1` and `array2` instead of arrays, the following solution should also work (a variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22015771/7256039)):

```js
var array1 = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [4, 5, 6, 7]
]
var array2 = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
]


var result = array1.map(function (e1, i) {
  return { array1: e1, array2: array2[i] }
})

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array map function:

```js
var array1 = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]];
var array2 = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h']];

var array3 = array1.map(function (e, i) {
    return [e, array2[i]];
});

console.log(array3);
```