# Array of objects with key/value pairs from given arrays of keys & values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to return an array of key-value pairs: `[{"a": 1},{"b": 2},{"c": 3}]` from a given array of keys: `["a", "b", "c"]` and an array of values: `[1, 2, 3]`

I have tried this:

```
let arr = [], obj = {}, key, val;
const keyValuePairs = (k, v) => {
  if (k.length === v.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
      key = k[i]; val = v[i];
      arr[i] = {key: val};
    }
  } return arr;
};

keyValuePairs(["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3]);
```

But it's returning - `[ { key: 1 }, { key: 2 }, { key: 3 } ]`

How can I do it?

Comment: Try changing `arr[i] = {key: val};` to `arr[i] = {[key]: val};`

Comment: @Hasan - Thanks a lot. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting a new enough browser, or are using babel, there is a new syntax that allows this easily:

`arr[i] = {[key]: val};`

Otherwise you will need to use multiple lines to set the key

```
let arr = [], obj = {}, key, val;
const keyValuePairs = (k, v) => {
  if (k.length === v.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
      key = k[i]; val = v[i];
      var newObj = {};
      newObj[key] = val;
      arr[i] = newObj;
    }
  } return arr;
};
```

Just general code comments: You have a bunch of variables out of the scope of the function. It's also quite verbose. You can write the entire function like this:

```
const keyValuePairs = (k, v) => (
    k.map((key, index) => ({ [key]: v[index] }))
);
```

Comment: If you  are going to discuss this new syntax, why not give its name, and even a reference?

Comment: Yeah, it's quite verbose. `[key]` is the key here though. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```js
a = ["a", "b", "c"], b = [1, 2, 3]

c = a.map((k, i) => ({[k]: b[i]}))

console.log(JSON.stringify(c))
```

[How do I zip two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/how-do-i-zip-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this(simple solution):

```js
var answer = keyValuePairs(["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3]);
console.log(answer);

function keyValuePairs(arrOne, arrTwo){
     var returnArr = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < arrOne.length; i++){
        var obj = {};
        obj[arrOne[i]] = arrTwo[i];
        returnArr[i] = obj;
     }
     
     return returnArr;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using [lodash](https://www.lodash.com) you can do this in one line with `_.map` or the vanilla `Array.prototype.map` and using the index `i` to stripe across the arrays.

```
var keys = 'abc'.split('');
var values = '123'.split('');
var result = _.map(keys, (key, i) =>  ( { [keys[i]] : values[i] } ) );
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

yields:
`[{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"},{"c":"3"}]`

you can also continue this pattern dimensionally:

```
var keys = 'abc'.split('');
var values = '123'.split('');
var valuesValues = 'xyz'.split('');
var result = _.map(keys, (key, i) => ( { [keys[i]] : { [ values[i] ]: valuesValues[i] } } ) );
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

yields:
`[{"a":{"1":"x"}},{"b":{"2":"y"}},{"c":{"3":"z"}}]`

Answer (score 0):

> you can use reduce method also as per your requirement.

see below example..

```js
let keys = ["a", "b", "c"], 
    values = [1, 2, 3],
    result = keys.reduce((r,v,i)=>r.concat({[v]:values[i]}),[]);

console.log(result);;
```