# 2 different array to single array set

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to make this 2 different array

```
array1 = ["ramu", "raju", "ravi"] ;
array2 = [10, 20, 30];
```

want to be in single array name

```
arrayNeed =[{name:"ramu",amt:10},{name:"raju",amt:20},{name:"ravi",amt:30}];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to zip array1 and array2. You should use map for this:

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
array1 = ["ramu", "raju", "ravi"] ;
array2 = [10, 20, 30];    
arrayNeed = array1.map((x, i) => ({name: x, amt: array2[i]}))
```

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Related to:

- [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function)
- [How do I zip two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/how-do-i-zip-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run `forEach` on the first array. This will accept a callback function with two args: item(one at a time), index of that item in the array.

Since you'll have the `index`, you can simply add a key named `amt` with a value of `array2`'s value at `index`

Try this

```
array1 = ["ramu", "raju", "ravi"] ;
array2 = [10, 20, 30];
arrayNeed = [];

array1.forEach((item, index) => {
  arrayNeed.push({ name: item, amt: array2[index] });
})
```

A **short-hand** syntax could also be:

```
arrayNeed = array1.map((item, index) => ({ name: item, amt: array2[index] }))
```

or

```
arrayNeed = array2.map((item, index) => ({ amt: item, name: array1[index]  }))
```

Comment: @ionDev Since you are using Angular (and I guess typescript), you can use map instead of the old foreach. No need to push anything. See my answer.

Comment: I'm just trying to enhance my answer. Nothing wrong with that I guess. I'll also add any other way of doing this in the near future if I find one.