# How to solve array question without hardcoding?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**how do you produce these objects ?**

```
let obs = [
    { car: cars[0], color: colors[0] },
    { car: cars[1], color: colors[1] },
    { car: cars[2], color: colors[2] }
]
```

**from these arrays without hard coding**

```
let cars = ["audi", "audi", "audi"]
let colors = ["darkgrey", "red", "silver"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I zip two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/how-do-i-zip-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: I just need to clarify something, will cars and colors be the same length at all times?

Comment: One-off code may not be an issue for a one-off problem, but writing generic code is usually better since reusability is always a factor of managing complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to produce an array of objects:

```js
const cars = ["audi", "audi", "audi"]
const colors = ["darkgrey", "red", "silver"]

const result = cars.map((car, i) => ({
  car,
  color: colors[i]
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `forEach` loop with an index and `push` new objects by choosing corresponding elements from each array:

```js
let cars = ["audi", "audi", "audi"];
let colors = ["darkgrey", "red", "silver"];

let result = [];
cars.forEach((car, i) => {
  result.push({car, color: colors[i]});
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` would also work well here - that way you don't have to manually define the array/push items :)

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous way of doing it. Personally I will prefer using a array [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, which will create a new array .

You can apply `map` method on any of the array and use it's index to retrieve value from another array

```js
let cars = ["audi", "audi", "audi"]
let colors = ["darkgrey", "red", "silver"];

let result = cars.map((item, index) => {
  return {
    car: item,
    color: colors[index]
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

You can also use conventional `for` loop , array `forEach` & array `reduce` also

Answer (score 1):

**Spent five more minutes, this worked too thanks Guys :)**

```
let cars = ["audi", "audiXL", "audiRover"]
let colors = ["silver", "darkgrey", "white"]

function matchCars () {   

    let matches = []

    for(let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {  
        let object = {car: cars[i], color: colors[i]}
        matches.push(object)
    }
    return matches

}

const answer = matchCars()
console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is really: How do I convert a [structure of arrays to an array of structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOS_and_SOA)?

A simple, general, solution looks like:

```js
let aos = soa2aos(
  [ 'car',  ['Civic', 'Integra'] ],
  [ 'year', [1994, 2001] ],
  [ 'color', ['grey', 'orange'] ]
);

console.log(aos);

function soa2aos(...soa) {
  return soa[0].reduce((aos, arr, i) => {
    let o = aos[i] = {};
    soa.forEach(([name, dat]) => o[name] = dat[i]);
    return aos;
  }, []);
}
```

[Read more about Parallel Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array)

I hope this helps!