# Combine two arrays as pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays that I'd like to combine, but in my searching I've only been able to find `Array.concat`.

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
let b = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

How do I combine these to create the following?

```
let combine = [
  [1,6],
  [2,7],
  [3,8],
  [4,9],
  [5,10]
]
```

Comment: Without using a loop?

Comment: `a.map((v, i) => [v, b[i]])`

Comment: Use a map to zip them together: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/how-do-i-zip-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both arrays have the same length, you can do the follow:

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
let b = [6,7,8,9,10]
let combine = a.map((e, i) => [e, b[i]]);
console.log(combine);
```