# How to combine first element of one array with first element of second array and so on

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having two arrays.

the first array contains dates

```
['2020-03-17,2020-03-19,2020-03-18,2020-03-12']
```

the second array contains time this array consists of time slot of two hours.

```
['11:00', '13:00','15:00', '17:00','19:00', '21:00', '23:00']
```

finally, I need the result to look like this:

```
['2020-03-17,11:00,13:00','2020-03-19,15:00,17:00','2020-03-18,19:00,21:00']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: what is the connection point between two array ?

Comment: @prasanth each pair of times goes with a date

Comment: but `2020-03-12` from 1st array is not there in the expected result. what is the logic for that?

Comment: @palaѕн because there are only 3 pairs of times, the last element in that array doesn't form a pair

Comment: Yes you're right @jack. the last element which does'nt form any pair should be excluded in new result

Comment: Is the first array supposed to be like that? It's currently holding a single string element containing multiple dates. Shouldn't each date be its own string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break this down for a bit; the first thing to do is to define a function that returns pairs of items from an array, like this:

```js
function timePairs(times)
{
    const result = []
    // i gets incremented by two each time, so make sure there are enough items
    // to pick
    for (let i = 0, n = times.length; i + 2 <= n; i += 2) {
        result.push([times[i], times[i + 1]])
    }
    return result
}
```

The resulting array would look like this:

```
[['11:00', '13:00'], ['15:00', '17:00'], ['19:00', '21:00']]
```

Then, each pair should be matched by a date; this can be accomplished by using a [zip operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22015771/1338292), which can be implemented using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

The map operation takes a function that gets called for each item, and it's expected to return the new value.

```js
timePairs(times).map((pair, index) => {
  return [dates[index], ...pair].join(',')
});
```

We use a small trick above; instead of writing `[dates[index], pair[0], pair[1]]`, it uses the `...` operator to shorten the code.

All together, it looks like this:

```js
const dates = ['2020-03-17','2020-03-19','2020-03-18','2020-03-12']
const times = ['11:00', '13:00','15:00', '17:00','19:00', '21:00', '23:00'];

function timePairs(times)
{
  const result = []
  for (let i = 0, n = times.length; i + 1 < n; i += 2) {
    result.push([times[i], times[i + 1]])
  }
  return result
}

const result = timePairs(times).map((pair, index) => {
  return [dates[index], ...pair].join(',')
});

console.log(result);
```

### Faster!

You can do this with a single loop as well, just keep two pointers for dates & pairs:

```js
const dates = ['2020-03-17','2020-03-19','2020-03-18','2020-03-12']
const times = ['11:00', '13:00','15:00', '17:00','19:00', '21:00', '23:00'];

result = []
for (let i = 0, j = 0, n = times.length >> 1; i != n; i++, j += 2) {
  result.push(dates[i] + ',' + times[j] + ',' + times[j + 1])
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Withdrew comment and referred to your answer in mine.  Hope that's okay

Comment: Is there any way to compare two arrays like [2020-03-19, 12:30,14:00]  and [2020-03-19, 12:00,14:00] and the result should be true, but as of now it is not a match but contains the similar time.

Comment: @TonyZhao how should that comparison take place? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Say one user is  attending an event of two hrs on a date say 2020-03-19 at start time 10:00 and end time 12:00. and another user want to add in an event  on same date but time is 10:30 to 12:30. but first user is already busy in another event that time. so system must say that first user  is not available in your selected date and time.

Comment: You'd have to detect time overlaps, by sorting on first time ... then iterate over the array, and stop when previous and current overlap

Answer (score 5):

## Pairing Arrays

If both arrays are in order and every pair of time is associated with a date, you can multiply the date index by 2 to get the first time, then add one to get the ending time.

```js
let dates = ['2020-03-17', '2020-03-19', '2020-03-18', '2020-03-12']
let times = ['11:00', '13:00', '15:00', '17:00', '19:00', '21:00', '23:00']

let dateTime = [];

for (let i in dates) {

  let timeIndex = i * 2;
  let startTime = times[timeIndex]
  let endTime = times[timeIndex + 1]

  if (endTime)
    dateTime.push( [dates[i], startTime, endTime].join(',') )
}

console.log(dateTime)
```

---

#### Note

The data in the OP had flaws that need to be addressed or corrected:

1. The date array was one string. This answer corrects that by making each date a separate element.  If that is not the case, simply extract the dats and split on the comma (i.e., `dates.pop().split(',')`)
2. <strike>The description was that each date has a pair of times, but it is questionable if that is always the case.  The last date indicates it only has one associated time.</strike> (see update)
3. If the timing pair occurs often, consider a more functional approach as offered in Jack's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60756349/10408280

#### Update

1. Comments revealed that if the last date does not have two times, it is excluded from the results. This answer has been updated to accommodate that instruction; however, this leaves a question concerning data quality.

   > What happens if times are missing for internal dates?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let array1 = ['2020-03-17,2020-03-19,2020-03-18,2020-03-12'];
array1 = array1.join().split(',');
const array2 = ['11:00', '13:00', '15:00', '17:00', '19:00', '21:00', '23:00'];

const merge = []
let index2 = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  if (array2[index2 + 1]) {
    merge.push(array1[i] + ',' + array2[index2] + ',' + array2[index2 + 1])
  }
  index2 += 2;
}
console.log(merge)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach` on dates array and combine elements from times array.

```js
const dates = ["2020-03-17", "2020-03-19", "2020-03-18"];
const times = ["11:00", "13:00", "15:00", "17:00", "19:00", "21:00"];

const merge = (dates, times) => {
  const res = [];
  dates.forEach((date, i) =>
    res.push(`${date},${times[i * 2]},${times[i * 2 + 1]}`)
  );
  return res;
};

console.log(merge(dates, times));
```