# Convert two arrays into array of pairs

Tags: javascript

I have arrays like:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

and I would like to get:

```
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
```

Is there some elegant (functional) way to do this, or will I have to use loops and indexes?

Comment: why elegant? what does not work?

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/how-do-i-zip-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: @493msi Thanks, couldn't find it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you consider something like this "elegant"?

```
a.map((x, idx) => [x, b[idx]]);
```

Comment: I'd use slightly different variable names and `i` not `idx` but this is good

Answer (score 0):

> **Option 1**

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    b = [1, 2, 3];

var zip = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
   zip.push([a[i], b[i]]);
}
```

OR to use fewer lines i.e. more *'elegant'* approach:

> **Option 2**

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    b = [1, 2, 3];

var zip = (b, a) => b.map((k, i) => [k, a[i]]);
// Instead of the for loop
// [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
```