# combining two array elements into one element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to combine two arrays in the following way.

```
var x = [{'d1':'3'}, {{'d2':'4'}}, {{'d3':'5'}}]
var y = [{'c1':'3'}, {{'c2':'4'}}, {{'c3':'5'}}]
```

my result should look like this

```
z = [
{'d1':'3', 'c1':'3' },
{'d1':'4', 'c1':'4' },
{'d1':'5', 'c1':'5' },
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I zip two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/how-do-i-zip-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: @user120242 it isn't a zip operation, as you end up with a flat array, not an array of tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bracket notation for the objects is wrong.  You have two sets of brackets instead of one.
Simple map that merges the objects using index position and spread operator.

```js
var x = [{'d1':'3'}, {'d2':'4'}, {'d3':'5'}]
var y = [{'c1':'3'}, {'c2':'4'}, {'c3':'5'}]

console.log(
z=x.map((x,i)=>([{...x,...y[i]}]))
)

    var x = [{'d1':'3'}, {'d2':'4'}, {'d3':'5'}]
    var y = [{'c1':'3'}, {'c2':'4'}, {'c3':'5'}, {'g6':'6'}]

    // needed for different length arrays, pads array with objects and y falsey check
    console.log(
    z=(x.length<y.length?x.concat(Array(y.length-x.length).fill({})):x)
         .map((x,i)=>([{...x,...y[i]||{}}]))
    )
```

Comment: This doesn't merge the objects into one.

Comment: Ah, misread it.  Fixed.  I'll retract the close vote too I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning up you syntax abit this is what I end up with:

```js
let x = [{d1:'3'}, {d2:'4'}, {d3:'5'}];
let y = [{c1:'3'}, {c2:'4'}, {c3:'5'}];

// create a new list to store the objects we'll create
let z = [];

[x, y].forEach(array => {
  // loop through the values for this line
  for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // handle case where we need to add more objects to our list
    if (z.length <= i) z.push({});
    // add new kay and value
    z[i][Object.keys(array[i])[0]] = array[i][Object.keys(array[i])[0]];
  }
});

console.log(z)
```

Note that by changing `[x,y]` to more lists such as `[x,y,z,w]` this code will still work assuming they are all the same size :)

View live example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mLork5vg/1/).