# Is there a way to add a key and value to and array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

my data structure has become a little messy since I have to pull separate data due to the API I'm using...

I have an array of objects called 'stocks' that looks like this:

```
[{id: "GOOGL", amount: 2},
{id: "IBM", amount: 10},
{id: "TSLA", amount: 9}]
```

and a separate array called 'currentPrice' that looks like this:

```
[1639, 125, 2213]
```

I am zipping as suggested in this previous posted answer:
[How do I zip two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/how-do-i-zip-two-arrays-in-javascript)

but it is pushing the element **outside** of the object, and just making it more complicated with nested arrays and objects..

Currently returning:

```
[[{id: "GOOGL", amount: 2}, 1639],
 [{id: "IBM", amount: 10}, 125],
 [{id: "TSLA", amount: 9}, 1639]]
```

Need:

```
[{id: "GOOGL", amount: 2, currentPrice: 1639},
 {id: "IBM", amount: 10, currentPrice: 125},
 {id: "TSLA", amount: 9, currentPrice: 1639}]
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let c = stocks.map(function(e, i){
        return [e, currentPrice[i]]
    })
    console.log(c)
})
```

Edited, thank you!

Comment: Sorry I meant at index 2 of array, thanks I appreciate any feedback

Comment: Something along the lines of `objs.map((obj, i) => ({ ...obj, currentPrice: prices[i] }))`