# How to use .map/.reduce from object return a map

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, reduce, array.prototype.map

Object look like this:

```
informations = {
    addresses: {
        0: {phone: 0},
        1: {phone: 1},
        2: {phone: 2},
        3: {phone: 3},
        4: {phone: 4},
        5: {phone: 5},
    },

    names: {
        0: n0,
        1: n1,
        2: n2,
        3: n3,
        4: n4,
        5: n5,
    }
}
```

How can I get result of `[{phone: 0, name: n0}, {phone:1, name: n1} .....{phone:5, name: n5}]`?

I was using `.map`, but gives me error of  **"Property 'map' does not exist on type"**.

Is there any fast way to write the code instead of using for() loop?

Comment: What is the finished result you are hoping to produce from this? If I know what the result should look like, I think I can build out the function you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) are array functions, not object functions. The only way to [iterate over an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/how-to-iterate-over-a-javascript-object) without creating an array first is `for...in`. If you don't mind creating an array, you can use `Object.entries`/`keys`/`values`, then do `reduce`, `map`, `forEach`, `for...of`.

In this case, the data is in a rather silly state as objects with monotonically increasing integer keys appear to be abused as arrays. You can convert those two objects to arrays using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), then ["zip"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function) the two together [using `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/how-do-i-zip-two-arrays-in-javascript) (this assumes these arrays are the same length):

```js
const informations = { addresses: { 0: {phone: 0}, 1: {phone: 1}, 2: {phone: 2}, 3: {phone: 3}, 4: {phone: 4}, 5: {phone: 5}, }, names: { 0: "n0", 1: "n1", 2: "n2", 3: "n3", 4: "n4", 5: "n5", } }

const addresses = Object.values(informations.addresses);
const names = Object.values(informations.names);
const result = addresses.map(({phone}, i) => ({
  phone, name: names[i]
}));
console.log(result);
```