# Can I have a map loop inside another map loop and not get duplicate results?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays :

```
const firstArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; 

const secondArr = [7,8,9,10,11,12];
```

I am trying to use a map loop like this :

```
arr.map(num1 => arr1.map(num2 => `${[num1]} ${num2}`))
```

I need the results of the second first array inside the results of the second one. Right now with the method i did it, Everything is duplicating:

```
0: (6) ["1,7", "1,8", "1,9", "1,10", "1,11", "1,12"]
1: (6) ["2,7", "2,8", "2,9", "2,10", "2,11", "2,12"]
2: (6) ["3,7", "3,8", "3,9", "3,10", "3,11", "3,12"]
3: (6) ["4,7", "4,8", "4,9", "4,10", "4,11", "4,12"]
4: (6) ["5,7", "5,8", "5,9", "5,10", "5,11", "5,12"]
5: (6) ["6,7", "6,8", "6,9", "6,10", "6,11", "6,12"]
```

Is it possible to have the results only once ?
My expected result is ['1,7' , '2,8' , " 3,9"] and so on.

Sorry I am still a noob :/ ...

Comment: It seems to me you are getting the results only once. "I need the results of the second first array inside the results of the second one. "  This can be interpreted different ways. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @SebastianSimon My expected result is ['1,7' , '2,8' , " 3,9"]  and so on... Thank you for your comment

Comment: Does this help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/how-do-i-zip-two-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `index` in `.map` as follows:

```js
const firstArr =  [1,2,3,4,5,6]; 
const secondArr = [7,8,9,10,11,12];

const res = firstArr.map((num1, i) =>`${[num1]},${secondArr[i]}`);

console.log(res);
```