# Is it possible to using forEach method for two arrays in same time?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr2 = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
```

Let's assume that I want to create a list like

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
```

by using template literal.

```
let x;
x = document.createElement('li');
x.innerHTML += `<span>${<arr1 index>}</span> <span>${<arr2 index>}</span>`
```

How can I do that ? Can we use forEach for two arrays in same time ?

Comment: Why not join them together first? `arr1.map((x,i) => [x,arr2[i]])`?

Comment: Or `arr1.flatMap` if you want a 1D array.

Comment: Can it also work for two storages? I ask it because I am beginner. Sorry :(

Comment: This would be more like `flatten(zip(arr1, arr2))`.  There is [no built-in `zip`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22015684/691711) though you can very easily make it.

Comment: why not using `for(let i = 0; i < arr1; i++){console.log(arr1[i] arr2[i])}`

Comment: BTW, `.innerHTML +=` is not really the best way to build HTML.

Comment: What do you suggest @trincot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no real magic here. You use an index variable, and let it increment:

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr2 = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

let ul = document.querySelector("ul");

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    for (let val of [arr1[i], arr2[i]]) {
        let span = document.createElement('span');
        span.textContent = val;
        li.appendChild(span);
    }
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

There are of course other ways to loop, like with `forEach`, but it comes down to the same principle.

BTW, don't use string literals (template literals) for combining HTML with content, as you might have `<` or `&` characters in the content, which really should be escaped. In some cases, not escaping those may lead to unexpected side effects. By creating the elements with `createElement` and assigning content to their `textContent` or `innerText` properties, you avoid those potential issues. Some libraries make it possible to do this with less code, in a more functional way.

As to the initial data: in object oriented languages, like JavaScript, it is better practice to put related values *together* in one object. In the example, 1 and "a" apparently have a connection, so -- if possible -- you should define the initial data structure as something like this:

```
var data = [
    { value: 1, name: "a" },
    { value: 2, name: "b" },
    { value: 3, name: "c" },
    { value: 4, name: "d" },
    { value: 5, name: "e" }
];
```

Comment: Let's try to avoid recommending jQuery in 2020+

Comment: Actually that was the clearest answer for such a beginner like me. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a `for()` loop instead:

```
const max = Math.max(arrA.length, arrB.length)

for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  const objA = arrA[i],
        objB = arrB[i]

  if ('undefined' !== typeof objA) {
    console.log({ objA })
  }
  if ('undefined' !== typeof objB) {
    console.log({ objB })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be more like `flatten(zip(arr1, arr2))`.  There is [no built-in `zip`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22015684/691711) though you can very easily make it and you can see `Array.flat` here: [MDN: `Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

const flatten = arr => arr.flat();
const zip = (a, b) => a.map((e, idx) => [e, b[idx]]);

const arr3 = flatten(zip(arr1, arr2));

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "kind of." What you can do is loop through one array with a forEach method, and use the optional argument `index` to get the value of the second array as well. Something like this:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr2 = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

arr1.forEach((value, index) => {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(arr2[index])
})
```

But if the data in the two arrays are at all related, you'd want to put the data in the same object, like this:

```
var arr = [
    {
        num: 1,
        letter: "a"
    },
    {
        num: 2,
        letter: "b"
    },
    {
        num: 3,
        letter: "c"
    }
];

arr.forEach(value => {
    console.log(value.num);
    console.log(value.letter);
})
```

Or you would want to use a regular for loop