# is it possible two make two arrays into one to create an x,y position array?

Tags: javascript

I am new to this so sorry if the question is dumb
I have two arrays, one is an array x values and the other one for y values.
I need to make an array that contains both, like [x1,y1,x2,y2...];
how do I make this using loops?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I zip two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/how-do-i-zip-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: So would your x-values be the even indices in your array and the y-values the odd indices? Or would an array of Objects work? `[{x:x1,y:y1},{x:x2,y:y2}...[x:xn,y:yn}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both the arrays contain the same number of elements then

```js
let arr = []
let xArr = [/*xValues*/]
let yArr = [/*yValues*/]

for (let i = 0; i < xArr.length; i++) {
    arr.push(xArr[i])
    arr.push(yArr[i])
}
```

Comment: yes that is what i was looking for! thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about objects?

```
var myObj = {
  x: [
    "1",
    "2"
  ],
  y: [
    "1",
    "2"
  ]
}
```

You can select it by:

```
myObj.x[0];
// "1"

myObj.x[1];
// "2"

myObj.y[0];
// "1"

myObj.y[1];
// "2"
```

Also, we all wonder things as programmers. Your question is not dumb for being curious.