# How to loop multiple objects in <td> in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have an Array with multiple Objects, now I want to loop each object as a `<tr>` in a `<table>`. I have done that.

However, these objects may contain multiple objects. Then I want to display all objects within 1 object in 1 `<td>`.

So this is the code what I have currently:

```html
<tr v-for="(data, index) in tableData" :key="index">
  <td
    v-for="(propertyValue, property, propertyIndex) in data.tableRow"
    :key="property"
  >
    <div>
      <span>{{ propertyValue }}</span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```js
const tableData = [
  {
    tableRow: {
      name: 'test',
    },
    tableRow1: {
      test: 'testComponent',
    },
  },
  {
    tableRow: {
      name: 'test 1',
    },
  },
  {
    tableRow: {
      name: 'test 2',
    },
  },
];
```

This should also happen for the other td's when there are multiple properties in the 2nd object.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: Calculate rowComponent per iteration

This can be done with a function that calculates the `rowComponent` for a particular column:

```js
const getRowComponent = ({ rowComponent }, index) =>
  // Only proceed if rowComponent exists
  rowComponent &&

  // Get the object values of rowComponent as an array
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values
  Object.values(rowComponent)

  // Get array element at specified index (undefined if not found)
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at
  .at(index)
```

The function would be used in the template per item of `tableData`, using the `rowData` index (named `propertyIndex` in this case):

```html
<tr v-for="(data, index) in tableData" :key="index">
  <td v-for="(propertyValue, property, propertyIndex) in data.rowData" :key="property" class="table-body-data">
    <div class="table-body-data-item">
      <span>{{ propertyValue }}</span>
                      
      <span>{{ getRowComponent(data, propertyIndex) }}</span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-multiple-loop-items-in-table-td?file=src/components/MyTable.vue)

However, if performance is to be considered (e.g., there are many rows and columns), this solution would be inefficient because:

- The function is called whenever this component is rendered, which can be multiple times.
- The function calls `Object.values()` on the same object for each column, thus repeating work that was done on the previous column.

If there are only a few columns, this hit probably wouldn't matter much.

#### Option 2: Compute collated data, and render that

A more performant solution is to use a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#computed-properties) that collates the corresponding `rowData` and `rowComponent`, returning an array that better facilitates accessing the paired data than the `tableData` object:

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/22015930/6277151
const zip = (a, b) => Array.from(Array(Math.max(b.length, a.length)), (_, i) => [a[i], b[i]])
const zipValues = (a, b) => zip(Object.values(a ?? {}), Object.values(b ?? {}))

// Computed table is an array of rows.
// Each row is an array of columns.
// Each column is an array of cell text.
const computedTableData = computed(() => tableData.map(item => zipValues(item.rowData, item.rowComponent)))
```

Then use the computed array in the template instead of `tableData`:

```html
<tr v-for="(row, rowIndex) in computedTableData" :key="rowIndex">
  <td v-for="(col, colIndex) in row" :key="colIndex" class="table-body-data">
    <div class="table-body-data-item">
      <span v-for="(cellText, cellTextIndex) in col" :key="cellTextIndex">{{ cellText }}</span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-multiple-loop-items-in-table-td-vppmgr?file=src/components/MyTable.vue)