# How to merge two arrays into single array of objects?

Tags: arrays, object

I'm trying to merge two arrays into one array consisting of objects created from the corresponding array items from the two original arrays:

Ex:

```
words = ['Toolbar', 'Vamoose', 'Arcade'];

clues = ['Strip of buttons', 'Get lost', 'Pinball wizards hangout'];
```

What I want:

```
output = [{'Toolbar', 'Strip of buttons'}, {'Vamoose', 'Get lost'}, {'Arcade', 'Pinball wizards hangout'}]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any preferred programming language?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I zip two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/how-do-i-zip-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: @ÉtienneMiret JavaScript. I've figured out how to combine the arrays into a single object but I want to create a single array consisting of multiple objects

Comment: Please update your description of the question, that you need this to be done in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
let words = ['Toolbar', 'Vamoose', 'Arcade'];
let clues = ['Strip of buttons', 'Get lost', 'Pinball wizards hangout'];

let data = [];

words.forEach((obj, index) => {
  obj = {
    word: words[index],
    clue: clues[index]
  };
  data.push(obj)
})

console.log(data)
[{
    "word": "Toolbar",
    "clue": "Strip of buttons"
},
{
    "word": "Vamoose",
    "clue": "Get lost"
},
{
    "word": "Arcade",
    "clue": "Pinball wizards hangout"
}]
```