# Update key value pair object in array from corresponding row/ key value pair in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, each with a years object with key valued pairs of the year and a value.  I want to create an updated version of array1 with the values for each row's years reduced by the values from the corresponding values in array2

i.e. A/Fred/2013 should be reduced from 16 by 3, to 13 and so on.

So far I have, but I'm not managing to update the array correctly

```
array1.forEach(r1 => {
    // Get the corresponding row from array2
    let array2Record = array2.find(r2 => r2.key1 === r1.key1 && r2.key2 === r1.key2);
    // Go through each of the years for this row in array1
    Object.entries(r1.years).forEach(keyValuePair => {
        // And reduce it by the value in array2
        keyValuePair.value = keyValuePair.value - array2Record.years[keyValuePair.key].value;
    })
})
```

This is the simplified version of the data

```
let array1 = [
    {
        "key1": "A",
        "key2": "Fred",
        "years": {
            "2013": 16,
            "2014": 11,
            "2015": 17
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": "A",
        "key2": "Jim",
        "years": {
            "2013": 1,
            "2014": 4,
            "2015": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": "B",
        "key2": "Mary",
        "years": {
            "2013": 1,
            "2014": 4,
            "2015": 3
        }
    }
]

let array2 = [
    {
        "key1": "A",
        "key2": "Fred",
        "years": {
            "2013": 3,
            "2014": 2,
            "2015": 7
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": "A",
        "key2": "Jim",
        "years": {
            "2013": 9,
            "2014": 3,
            "2015": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": "B",
        "key2": "Mary",
        "years": {
            "2013": 8,
            "2014": 3,
            "2015": 6
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data isn't small you could prefer to map the update array by keys and then use it thus avoiding `Array::find()`:

```js
const map = array2.reduce((r, e) => ((r[e.key1] ??= {})[e.key2] = e, r), {});

array1.forEach(e => {
  const found = map[e.key1]?.[e.key2];
  if(!found) return;
  for(const year in e.years){
    e.years[year] -= found.years[year]??0;
  }
});

console.log(array1);
```

```html
<script>

const array1 = [{"key1":"A","key2":"Fred","years":{"2013":16,"2014":11,"2015":17}},{"key1":"A","key2":"Jim","years":{"2013":1,"2014":4,"2015":3}},{"key1":"B","key2":"Mary","years":{"2013":1,"2014":4,"2015":3}}]
const array2 = [{"key1":"A","key2":"Fred","years":{"2013":3,"2014":2,"2015":7}},{"key1":"A","key2":"Jim","years":{"2013":9,"2014":3,"2015":1}},{"key1":"B","key2":"Mary","years":{"2013":8,"2014":3,"2015":6}}]

</script>
```

An example with 3 keys:

```js
 let array2 = [
    {
        "key1": "A",
        "key2": "Fred",
        key3: 1,
        "years": {
            "2013": 16,
            "2014": 11,
            "2015": 17
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": "A",
        "key2": "Jim",
        key3: 2,
        "years": {
            "2013": 1,
            "2014": 4,
            "2015": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": "B",
        "key2": "Mary",
        key3: 3,
        "years": {
            "2013": 1,
            "2014": 4,
            "2015": 3
        }
    }
]
 
const map = array2.reduce((r, e) => (((r[e.key1] ??= {})[e.key2] ??= {})[e.key3] = e, r), {});

console.log(map);
```

A benchmark to update 3 students from 3, 30, 300 and 3000 students (replaced names with integers):

```
` Chrome/121
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                   n=3       |      n=30       |      n=300       |      n=3000     
Alexander      1.81x  x1m 168 | 1.00x   x1m 337 |  1.00x x100k 209 |   1.00x x10k 213
Andrew Parks   1.20x  x1m 111 | 3.09x x100k 104 |  4.73x x100k 988 |   5.12x  x1k 109
Onur Dogan     1.00x x10m 928 | 1.60x   x1m 538 | 17.94x  x10k 375 | 206.10x x100 439
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const keys = [...Array(3000).fill().keys()];
keys.forEach((k, i) => {
  const idx = Math.random()*(keys.length-i)|0 + i;
  [keys[i], keys[idx]] = [keys[idx], k];
});
let idx = 0;
const $chunk = () => [{"key1":"A","key2":keys[idx++],"years":{"2013":16,"2014":11,"2015":17}},{"key1":"A","key2":keys[idx++],"years":{"2013":1,"2014":4,"2015":3}},{"key1":"B","key2":keys[idx++],"years":{"2013":1,"2014":4,"2015":3}}]
const array2 = [{"key1":"A","key2":1,"years":{"2013":3,"2014":2,"2015":7}},{"key1":"A","key2":2, "years":{"2013":9,"2014":3,"2015":1}},{"key1":"B","key2":3,"years":{"2013":8,"2014":3,"2015":6}}]

const $input = [];
const array1 = $input;

// @benchmark Andrew Parks

array1.forEach(({key1, key2, years}) => Object.entries(
    array2.find(({key1: a, key2: b}) => a===key1 && b===key2)?.years ?? {}
  ).forEach(([year, count]) => years[year] -= count)
)
array1;

// @benchmark Onur Dogan

array1.concat(array2).reduce((tot, val) => { 
const index = tot.findIndex(({ key1, key2 }) => key1 === val.key1 && key2 === val.key2);

if(index > -1){
  Object.keys(val.years).forEach(yearKey => {
    tot[index].years[yearKey] -= val.years[yearKey];
  });
}
else {
    tot.push(val);
}

   return tot;
}, []);

// @benchmark Alexander

const map = array2.reduce((r, e) => ((r[e.key1] ??= {})[e.key2] = e, r), {});

array1.forEach(e => {
  const found = map[e.key1]?.[e.key2];
  if(!found) return;
  for(const year in e.years){
    e.years[year] -= found.years[year]??0;
  }
});
array1;

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: I quite like this solution as it uses the keys and is more straightforward.  However, I want to add a 3rd key and the map doesn't find anything.  
const map = array2.reduce((r, e) => ((r[e.key1] ??= {}[e.key2] ??={}) [e.key3] = e, r), {});
 
console.log(map)
array1.forEach(e => {
  const found = map([e.key1]?.[e.key2]?.[e.key3]);

Comment: @Chris added an example how to make a map with 3 keys

Comment: Great, thanks Alexander.  Am I right in thinking the "const years = {};" is superfluous?

Comment: @Chris oops, a leftover, will clean up later

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

You can do so by [zipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipping_(computer_science)) the arrays using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), then updating the `years` property value. To create the new years property value you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
let array1 = [
  {
    key1: "A",
    key2: "Fred",
    years: {
      2013: 16,
      2014: 11,
      2015: 17,
    },
  },
  {
    key1: "A",
    key2: "Jim",
    years: {
      2013: 1,
      2014: 4,
      2015: 3,
    },
  },
  {
    key1: "B",
    key2: "Mary",
    years: {
      2013: 1,
      2014: 4,
      2015: 3,
    },
  },
];

let array2 = [
  {
    key1: "A",
    key2: "Fred",
    years: {
      2013: 3,
      2014: 2,
      2015: 7,
    },
  },
  {
    key1: "A",
    key2: "Jim",
    years: {
      2013: 9,
      2014: 3,
      2015: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    key1: "B",
    key2: "Mary",
    years: {
      2013: 8,
      2014: 3,
      2015: 6,
    },
  },
];

const result = array1.map((arr1Value, i) => {
  // here we zip i. e. we get the i-th value of both arrays 
  const arr2value = array2[i]; 
  
  // here we merge/ reduce both i-th values
  // by creating a new object which has the same keys
  // as the original objects but the value is set to the difference
  // between both input array values for a specific year
  const updatedYearsProperty = Object.keys(arr1Value.years).reduce(
    (obj, key) => (
      (obj[key] = (arr1Value.years[key] ?? 0) - (arr2value.years[key] ?? 0)), obj
    ),
    {}
  );
   
  // now we just return a new object which has all of the same properties as the original, BUT
  // we update the years value with the new object we've created above
  return {
    ...arr1Value,
    years: updatedYearsProperty,
  };
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```css
/* Stackoverflow: show only console */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

### Additional remarks on the solution

This method assumes, that both the array contain the same number of elements and that objects that should be merged are in the same position within both array (i. e. e.g. both *Fred*s are the first elements in the array). One can also make it work without that being the case. If the number of items is relatively small (few hundreds to thousands as a rule-of thumb) you can just replace the line `const arr2value = array2[i];`  with `const arr2value = array2.find(x => x.key1 == arr1Value.key1 && x.key2 == arr1Value.key2) ?? {}` and it'll work no matter the order.

If you are really concerned with performance and have a few-thousand and more items it's a bit more involved as you would need a lookup table e.g. using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) so you could do that in linear time `O(n)`. Something with [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (as mentioned above) would run in `O(n²)`.

By using the [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) I handle the cases where a particular year might only be present in the first or second array by using a default value of `0` in that case. You can remove that check if that cannot be the case with your data.

In terms of runtime this runs in `O(n)` and only does a single iteration through your data and therefore is pretty much as fast as it gets.

I also treated everything as [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) which is generally a good practice in order to prevent bugs. That also means the original input value has remained untouched or better unchanged. The result is (as the data currently is) a [deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying) of your input.

#### See also

There are many possible ways to zip arrays in JavaScript e.g. using [`map()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22015930/17487348) (as I did here) or [generators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72221748/17487348): See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/zip-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: judging from the OP's code the OP wants to modify the original array plus search by the keys and don't rely on the order

Comment: Well, that's a guess. Just because that's what OP is currently doing doesn't mean that's what is intended to be done. Might very well be that the OP is not even aware of this distinction, which is why I explicitly pointed that out in my answer. He might decide to need this or he might not. Only thing we know is that we don't know. I am just providing an option and a reason why that might be a good idea. I'm not saying this is the way it has to be done. That's up to OP. PS: by that reason (*we don't know*) I also think this doesn't justify a downvote to my mind.

Comment: your solution is the farthest from what the OP tries to achieve with his code...

Comment: Thanks for Mushroomator for your detailed response.  I believe the two arrays are likely to have the same number of rows, years in each row and be in the same order.  But I'd be nervous about assuming this is definitely the case.  If your solution then breaks, I'm not sure it's the right one.  There are c.500 rows so speed is not a major concern.  That said, I wonder if @AndrewParks answer using find is the simplest and best answer.

Comment: @Chris For 500 items it doesn't really matter much if you use an array (`O(n²)`) or a lookup of some sort (`O(n)`). Therefore in that case you could just replace the line `const arr2value = array2[i]; ` with `const arr2value = array2.find(x => x.key1 == arr1Value.key1 && x.key2 == arr1Value.key2) ?? {}` and the order no longer matters. I've updated my answer as well :)

Comment: @Mushroomator, doesn't this assume that they have the same keys and are in the same order?

Comment: There are no assumptions on the order when you use `find()`. You somehow have to find the matching entry though, no matter how. Now I am matching on the keys, since they always match in your sample data, so `A` and `Fred` in array 1 matches with `A` and `Fred` in array two. If you only need to match on one key just remove the `&&` condition. Not sure what you match on, but you only have four options: 1. Match on position (-> this would be the zipping approach -> not what you want), 2. match on `key1`, 3. match on `key2` or 4. match on `key1` and `key2`. Options 2-4 use the `find()` approach.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can do it by using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get a new array by combining them. Then reduce the year values by matching and looping them one by one with a `forEach`. 
It matches any records by matching `key1` and `key2` values so if you want to match more arrays, then you just need to combine them by using [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
let array1 = [
    {
        "key1": "A",
        "key2": "Fred",
        "years": {
            "2013": 16,
            "2014": 11,
            "2015": 17
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": "A",
        "key2": "Jim",
        "years": {
            "2013": 1,
            "2014": 4,
            "2015": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": "B",
        "key2": "Mary",
        "years": {
            "2013": 1,
            "2014": 4,
            "2015": 3
        }
    }
]

let array2 = [
    {
        "key1": "A",
        "key2": "Fred",
        "years": {
            "2013": 3,
            "2014": 2,
            "2015": 7
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": "A",
        "key2": "Jim",
        "years": {
            "2013": 9,
            "2014": 3,
            "2015": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": "B",
        "key2": "Mary",
        "years": {
            "2013": 8,
            "2014": 3,
            "2015": 6
        }
    }
]

const reducedArray = array1.concat(array2).reduce((tot, val) => { 
    const index = tot.findIndex(({ key1, key2 }) => key1 === val.key1 && key2 === val.key2);
    
    if(index > -1){
       Object.entries(val.years).forEach(([year, count]) =>
         tot[index].years[year] -= count
       );
    }
    else {
       tot.push(val);
    }

    return tot;
}, []);

console.log(reducedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find each matching object in `array2`, and then for each year, update each count.

Optional chaining `?.` and the nullish coalescing operator `??` are used to handle cases where there is no matching object in `array2`, by providing an empty array `{}` to `Object.entries`.

```js
const array1 = [{"key1":"A","key2":"Fred","years":{"2013":16,"2014":11,"2015":17}},{"key1":"A","key2":"Jim","years":{"2013":1,"2014":4,"2015":3}},{"key1":"B","key2":"Mary","years":{"2013":1,"2014":4,"2015":3}}]
const array2 = [{"key1":"A","key2":"Fred","years":{"2013":3,"2014":2,"2015":7}},{"key1":"A","key2":"Jim","years":{"2013":9,"2014":3,"2015":1}},{"key1":"B","key2":"Mary","years":{"2013":8,"2014":3,"2015":6}}]


array1.forEach(({key1, key2, years}) => Object.entries(
    array2.find(({key1: a, key2: b}) => a===key1 && b===key2)?.years ?? {}
  ).forEach(([year, count]) => years[year] -= count)
)

console.log(array1)
```